# Access to TrueDepth from Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit, truedepth-camera

I try to use TrueDepth data from iPhoneX(Xs, Xr, new iPadPro) for Unity App. 
Current ARKit plugin for Unity doesn't seem to access to TrueDepth. So I think I need to create native plugin in Objective-c. 
How to create a plugin which enable Unity to access to TrueDepth? 
Just obtaining RGB and D from iOS is enough.

Basically, I would like to make similar app in the link with Unity.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/streaming_depth_data_from_the_truedepth_camera

Comment: Hey did you get nay option here?

Comment: Plugin to access to Truedepth for Unity.
https://github.com/AtsushiSuzuki/unity-depthcapture-ios

Comment: Any updates on this?